# Host flask api on server locally

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I need to host my API on the server. How is it possible? I have done by virtualenv on my computer but I need to host it now on my company server I need to host exactly like virtualenv ? Or there is some other way as in PHP we use xamp?

Comment: Would Docker be an option for you? If you get your application running in a local  Docker container, you could use the same setup in production

Answer (score 0):

You simply install flask in a virtualenv or not, and do `flask run app.py` to run the server, just like the documentation says.

Alternatively, if you want a feature set similar to Apache HTTPd, then you can look into uWSGI